# Are VBA strings immutable?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I know .NET (and therefore VB.NET) strings are immutable.  However, I'm using VBA 7.0 in Excel 2010.  Are strings there immutable?  I'm doing a lot of string processing and for small quantities, some (direct) string manipulation is fine, but I'm worried it won't scale - since every additional character moved from one string to another might create yet another instance of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While VB.NET strings are immutable, as mandated by System.String, VBA (including VB6?) strings can be mutated (such as with `Mid$`). See [Alex K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21676158/2864740) and note the `StrPtr` result after the operations.

---

Original answer; supported by documentation, in opposition to a counter-example.

*VBA strings are immutable.*

Just as with VB.NET, there is no way to "replace part of" or "append to" a string without creating a new string. Whether or not this matters - as modern computers are pretty darn fast - depends on the actual algorithm, data, and environment.

---

Unlike .NET documentation, such a behavior reference for VBA is [becoming] difficult to track down. From [MS-VBAL: 2.1 Data Values and Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx), we find this rare little gem

> *Individual data values are immutable.* This means that there are no defined mechanisms available within a VBA Environment that can cause a data value to change into another data value.

where Strings represent "individual data values".

Comment: This answer is wrong but I sympathise with the poster because even at date of posting this comment, Microsoft still claim they are immutable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/string-basics -- MIcrosoft say crazy stuff! See my last Answer.

Comment: @www-0av-Com Your link is for VB.NET. It is correct in saying strings are immutable because they are immutable in .NET. VBA is a separate language.

Answer (score 9):

They are immutable, except when they exhibit mutable behaviour, then they are not.

For example assignment via `mid$()` is significantly faster than a normal new-string-from-assignment.

```
Dim s As String

s = "ABC"

Debug.Print s, StrPtr(s)

'// -> ABC            122899836

Mid$(s, 1, 1) = "Z"

Debug.Print s, StrPtr(s)

'// -> ZBC            122899836     

s = "??" & Right$(s, 1)

Debug.Print s, StrPtr(s)

'// -> ??C            196635748
```

Comment: +1 I was just gonna say `Dim str As String: str = "this string": Debug.Print VarPtr(str), StrPtr(str): Mid(str, 3, 2) = "at": Debug.Print VarPtr(str), StrPtr(str)`

Answer (score 0):

VBA strings ARE mutable. Alex K's answer is wrong but he is right about the `Mid()=` fudge in Microsoft's VB.Net which rightly claims they are immutable -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/string-basics -- despite supporting `Mid()=`.

So, in all VB6, VBA, VB.Net, you can use (eg) `Mid(a$, 1, 2)="hi"` as stated in Alex's reply, to overwrite parts of a string. However, as user2864740 points out, only VB6 & VBA do this extremely quickly. This is tested code in VB6(VBA) & VB.Net..

```
Dim n1&, start!, bigstring$
bigstring$ = Space(10 ^ 6)
start = timer() ' in vb.Net this is function with "timer = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - Today.Ticks) / 10000000.0#"

For n1 = 1 To 5000
    Mid(bigstring, n1, 1) = "1"
Next

Debug.Print("Elapsed millisecs: " & (timer() - start!) * 1000.0! & " over cycle count of " & n1 - 1)
```

On large strings over a megabyte, this technique is essential for speed and is thus scalable. On VBA, it does this in under a millisecond. However, in VB.Net it is stunningly inefficient -- this same test takes 7 seconds on a 3GHz CPU, about 1ms per iteration. With increasing from 5000 to 1 million iterations, VBA still only takes 40ms. VB.Net would take 30 mins. Tip: In VB.Net, you can use `Dim BigByte() as byte` then `BigByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bigstring)` so you are working with a byte array. How to make that flexible and Unicode is beyond this topic.

Comment: VB.NET does a little "trick" to *re-assign* the variable to make it appear that the string has changed. The original string has _not_ changed. `Dim a$ = "Hello!" ; Dim b$ = a$ ; Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a$, b$)) ; MID(a$, 1) = "Goodbye" ; Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(a$, b$))`. This displays "True, False" (as using MID _re-assigns_ `a$` to a _new_ string, while leaving the original string unaltered). The System.String type in .NET is immutable, regardless of the languages that uses it. I've not confirmed in VB6/VBA.

Comment: Your reference link is for VB.NET where strings are immutable because they are immutable in .NET in principle, so that documentation is correct. In VBA, where there is no such restriction, strings are mutable.

Comment: Wrt. "So, in all VB6, VBA, VB.Net, ..". Anyway, I've updated my answer (not this answer) to reflect to Alex K's answer wrt VBA/VB6 behavior.

Comment: Thanks all for your updates. You all 3 saved me much pain as I was about to migrate a VB6 web server (which uses `Mid()=` everywhere for speed) to VB.Net. I'll have to make even bigger changes than at first thought.

Comment: @user2864740 .. seeing as I helped you correct your answer, without correcting it myself, upvoted your reply above, and have added a wealth of depth to the general question, how about an upvote? I'm no glory hunter, but there are certain things I can't do without certain levels. Quid pro quo huh? :)